# How to create a tab based application in mac os?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am new in Mac os and trying to create a tab based application in XCode.
The tab based application should different different information in each tab.

I have created a cocoa based application and that have already a .xib file.

Can anyone please give me link or any idea to start to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Somebody has forget, that there is a search engine called "Google" ;)

Comment: Googleness! Some peoples sickness.. peace.. :)

Answer (score 1):

AppKit comes with a load of `NSView` subclasses that are designed to help you bring extra functionality to you apps, one of which is [`NSTabView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTabView_Class/index.html).

You can do quite a lot with tab view (including dynamically adding and removing tabs as per the user's needs). If, however, you want a more custom looking App, like google chrome, or safari, then you will probably need to create you own subclass of `NSView`.

Comment: To add the tab view to your XIB file: open your XIB file, go to the panel on the left, go down to where all the interface components are, search tab, and drag the tab view into your window. You can modify the properties in the inspector on the right.